# How to overwrite a feature of a column in subclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

In our application there is an entity class which is having a property (private long version) with @Version annotation and there are lot of classes which are 
extending this entity. We have implemented versioning to handle optimistic locking.
But in one of those subclasses we dont want that feature. 
So my question is how can I overwrite that feature in the subclass ?

Code :

**Employee.java :**

```
@MappedSuperclass
class Employee {

@Id
@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
private String name;

@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION")
private long version

//setters and getters 

}
```

**PermEmployee.java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERM_EMP")
class PermEmployee extends Employee {

@Column(name = "SAL")
private long salary;

//setters and getters 

}
```

Currently PERM_EMP table is also having  VERSION column and its getting incremented with each update which we dont want for PERM_EMP table.
Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try attributeOverride:

```
@AttributeOverride(name = "version", column = @Column(name = "perm_version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public class PermEmployee extends Employee{
}
```

More on it here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html